# How to implement a Many-to-Many RNN in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

[image]

The below code gives me all the hidden state values of the unrolled RNN.

```
hidden_states,final_hidden_state = tf.nn.dyanamic_rnn(...)
```

How do I multiply **each** of the `hidden_states` with the weight **"Why"** shown in the figure.

I find this confusing because the shape of `hidden_states` is `[mini_batch_size,max_seq_length,num_of_hidden_neurons]`

Do I have to make some kind of `for` loop for each of the hidden state and then multiply by **Why** to get the **y** values?

Thanks !